# Node.js script failed to start with systemctl

Tags: node.js, linux, debian, systemctl

I need to run my node.js script automatically from my remote machine with systemctl.

I already made a .service file and put that into `/etc/systemd/system/`. Here's the .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=laporan

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/laporan/nodeserver/server.js
Restart=always
User=nobody
Group=root
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/laporan/nodeserver

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But every time I try to start the service, it returns an error as follows (output of `systemctl status laporan`):

```
● laporan.service - laporan
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/laporan.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2016-09-12 09:15:06 WITA; 11min ago
  Process: 121690 ExecStart=/var/www/laporan/nodeserver/server.js (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 121690 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 12 09:15:05 kominfomdc systemd[1]: Unit laporan.service entered failed state.
Sep 12 09:15:06 kominfomdc systemd[1]: laporan.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Sep 12 09:15:06 kominfomdc systemd[1]: Failed to start laporan.
Sep 12 09:15:06 kominfomdc systemd[1]: Unit laporan.service entered failed state.
```

What exactly is this error about? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think that's how you start a node app. You are just specifying the JavaScript file here:

```
ExecStart=/var/www/laporan/nodeserver/server.js
```

You also need to specify the node executable, something like the following, if node is in the path.

```
ExecStart= node /var/www/laporan/nodeserver/server.js
```

If node isn't on the executable path, you must provide it:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /var/www/laporan/nodeserver/server.js
```

Comment: receive this kind of notice : Executable path is not absolute. my node is in the path as well

Comment: Well, i changed it to `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /var/www/laporan/nodeserver/server.js` and it run like hell. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Observe that, in some systems, node is located at /usr/bin/node, so test running full path (i.e. /usr/bin/node /dir/yourapp.js or /usr/local/bin/node /dir/yourapp.js) to see which one will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I had a somewhat strange issue. Node is on my path (in my EC2 instance) and running `node absolute_path_to_index.js` was running fine. However executing the exact same command in systemd was failing, apparently because systemd was using the default Node installation (it was node 8 apparently). So I ran `which node` and pasted the absolute path in systemd and this made the trick.

Comment: what if i want to use npm run start

Answer (score 7):

to give clarity of the error you are putting the **node** executable path is wrong.
To get the correct path you can use

```
$ which node // /usr/bin/node
```

in my case its different i get **/usr/bin/node** as path so in you **ExecStart**
copy the node path from the command line

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /var/www/laporan/nodeserver/server.js
```